# can't start Rails server - bunch of errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, server

I'm new on Ruby on Rails (actualy I'm new programming in general) and I tried to start a new server for my web app. I followed all the rules that were in the book, installed everything required (I hope I've installed it correctly), but it keeps giving me the following error:

My command ->
C:\Users\Júlia\work\demo>ruby bin/rails server

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:50:in `match?': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:50:in `chop_basename'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:374:in `plus'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:354:in `+'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:420:in `join'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/settings.rb:444:in `global_config_file'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/settings.rb:93:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:330:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:330:in `settings'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `configured_bundle_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `bundle_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:639:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:81:in `configure'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:194:in `definition'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:143:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Júlia/work/demo/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I'm so frustrated right now, I keep doing things apparently right but something always has to go wrong! Anyways, I hope someone will be able to help me here :(

Comment: What does `config/boot.rb` contain, anything you changed there? That being said, Ruby on Windows has been known to be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow GoRails guide to install RoR on windows it will be much easier.
Here it is: [Install Ruby On Rails on Windows 10](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10)

Also after installing it you may face some other issues related to your database ( whatever database you use) like you may have installed Postgresql on windows, so when after installing it on WSL you need to kill the one running on the port that WSL will use, and similar issues, all solved across the internet