# Having a problem with running 'bundle exec rspec'

Tags: ruby, class, rspec, exec, bundle

I am working on an educational project where I have to use `bundle exec rspec`. In my console, I am having this error:

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:50:in `match?': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:50:in `chop_basename'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:374:in `plus'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:354:in `+'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:420:in `join'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/settings.rb:444:in `global_config_file'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/settings.rb:93:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:330:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler.rb:330:in `settings'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/feature_flag.rb:21:in `block in settings_method'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/cli.rb:104:in `<class:CLI>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/cli.rb:6:in `<module:Bundler>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/exe/bundle:39:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/exe/bundle:39:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:128:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.28/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Seems like Pathname is encountering an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence. Unless you post some code and some verbatim strings via copy-and-paste, this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: The error seems to be coming from [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/54f6e0f2ef4ade2bdbd4e71093a0542459d4ed0e/bundler/lib/bundler/settings.rb#L444), and later fails [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2dd26bed86f721ed1982d00c3a0bd5ed37568e96/ext/pathname/lib/pathname.rb#L50).  I also see you're [not the first person to ask this exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69486728/cant-start-rails-server-bunch-of-errors), but I cannot see any answer for it.

Comment: Considering [this code I just linked above](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/54f6e0f2ef4ade2bdbd4e71093a0542459d4ed0e/bundler/lib/bundler/settings.rb#L437-L444), what is your `Bundler.rubygems.user_home`? Does it contain any non-UTF-8 characters? Could you try setting an alternative `ENV['BUNDLE_USER_HOME']`, to see if that changes the error?

Comment: If this is proving too hard to get working, you may wish to consider dropping back down to ruby version `2.7.x`, instead of `3.0.x`. Ruby version 3 is still fairly new, and support for Windows (as with most programming languages!) can be a little sketchy compared to unix-based systems.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with ruby 3.1.x. As mentioned by Tom Lor, I uninstalled it and installed 2.7.x During reinstallation, it asks if you want the outside encoder to default to UTF-8 (it didn't ask it for 3.1.x.

Check that box, and it will work.